# Footer doesn't look right in safari only

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Ok so there's a site i've been asked to look at and I can't seem to figure out why it only looks bad in safari. It looks fine in every other browser so far and I can't figure it out. The problem takes place in the footer of the document. Here's the link... [www.palettekids.com](http://www.palettekids.com) (I SWEAR IT'S NOT MY DESIGN :-))!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra `</div>` somewhere if you look at the source in safari it is outside of the `#container`. But in Chrome it is inside. The container is what is holding everything else in. Double check all your closing div's and remove the extra one.

Comment: Exactly. The style will work in other browsers only because they're more forgiving when it comes to handling poorly structured HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your code errors, like the missing ending tags, like `</div>, </body> and </html>` among other errors; probably all missing from footer.php. See [[Invalid] Markup Validation of   palettekids.com  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.palettekids.com/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think coords are supported in Safari:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_coords.asp

try using another method (margin perhaps)?